# Am I able to setup Android Studio to display a popup containing my TODO list?

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to become more productive whenever I start coding. Rather than arbitrarily choose a starting point each day, I would like to use my TODO list in Android Studio to drive me forward, but I'm still not in the habit of checking my TODO list manually.

I've looked in Settings under both the **Tools** -> **Startup Tasks** and **Editor** -> **TODO** sections, but as far as I can tell, neither provides a solution that I need.

Is there a setting to display my TODO upon starting up Android Studio, either by navigating to my first instance of TODO within my code or by having my TODO panel/window popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on "TODO" and select "Floating Mode", close your Android Studio. Next time you open your Android Studio, it will be popped up.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I'm glad it was such an easy solution!